# Why does my custom ContentType feature error on activation?

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I am creating a custom ContentType for SharePoint 2007 as a feature scoped to the site collection.  When I attempt to activate the feature, I get an error page with only this clue: "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Here are my XML files
feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Created by STSDEV at 5/5/2009 5:11:40 PM-->
<Feature
  Id="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  Title="Custom Document Content Type"
  Description="Custom Document Content Type"
  Version="1.0.0.0"
  Scope="Site"
  Hidden="false"
  ImageUrl="CustomDocumentContentType\Image.gif" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest
      Location="CustomDocumentContentType.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

and CustomDocumentContentType.xml:

```
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>-->
<!--Created by STSDEV at 5/5/2009 5:11:40 PM-->
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <ContentType ID="0X010100YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
               Name="Custom Document Content Type"
               Group ="Custom Document Content Types"
               Description="Custom Document Content Type inherits from Document"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>             
</Elements>
```

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out.

This line, `<ContentType ID="0X010100YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"`

Should be `<ContentType ID="0x010100YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"`

the "X" in the ID should be lowercase.

Keith

Comment: Nice work weeding that one out!  Those are the types of problems that drive me to pull what's left of my hair out.  +1 for your diligence to post your own solution.